# Get video stream from tcpip port (ArDrone) to Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, video, tcp

I am trying to obtain video from an IP webcam in particular that HD camera on ARdrone parrot 2.0, I can get the video stream either with MPEG4.2 soft encoder or with H264-like codec or with MJPEG-like codec and is sent by a tcpip port by the drone.

The point is that, I have already been able to display this video stream on ffplay (external program to Matlab) using win7, but I would like to save video in a variable on Matlab in order to use image proccesing with it and control the drone depending on what "it's seeing".

I have already looked up for this matter and have not found anything illuminating. So I will be very grateful if any of you know how to get this image straight from the tcpip port or even from ffplay program.